# MySQL slave server not executing drop user command

Tags: mysql, database, master-slave

I have two MySQL servers connected with Mater-Slave replication. When I am creating user by the command,

```
CREATE USER 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[some_password]';
```

user is created at master and in the slave. But when I am running query,

```
DROP USER 'someuser'@'%';
```

The master server delete the user from server **but the SLAVE server does not remove the user from its database.**

I don't know what is the problem with the slave here. Because if i create the user and drop it and again create the same user. `Replication gets stop as the salve server has the user already and duplicate user error is coming.` Can anybody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Any error on salve when it's get failed?

Comment: Error `Operation CREATE USER failed for 'some'@'%'' on query. Default database: '`. The query is failed because duplicate user entry as the slave server is not deleting the user when master deletes the user.

Comment: Any error while `DROP` query?

Comment: There is no error at master side. Slave has only the error as it is not deleting the user. When creating same user at master slave stops replication as it has already the user. **Clearly error duplicate user.** Error would not happen if slave drop the user as mater.

Comment: What is `binlog-do-db` and `binlog-ignore-db` config?

Comment: `binlog-ignore-db = mysql
binlog-ignore-db = test
binlog-ignore-db = information_schema
replicate-ignore-db = mysql
replicate-ignore-db = test
replicate-ignore-db = information_schema` There is no do db config as all databases are replicated except these three DBs.

Comment: As per Docs "ser privileges are replicated only if the mysql database is replicated. That is, the GRANT, REVOKE, SET PASSWORD, CREATE USER, and DROP USER statements take effect on the slave only if the replication setup includes the mysql database."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173056/discussion-between-hasanuzzaman-sattar-and-amogh).